not able to add bot in second teams channel not getting welcome in second, thrid channel but getting in first channel
not able to add bot in second teams channel not getting welcome in second, third channel but getting in first channel.
able to get welcome in second or third channel. but for now not getting.
please guide me how to solve this error. basically when I added bot in first channel it is created but when I created in second channel and try to added in second but not getting welcome but able to get welcome messed in case of first channel creation. I try with permutation but nothing works! not able to add bot in second teams channel not getting welcome in second, third channel but getting in first channel.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps/Code snippets, so that we can try it from our end.
